# Different output while running and debugging

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I want that to print tree.
So the problem is that my output from RUN differs with output from DEBUG and it seem like `__str__` (variable `self.__visited` is already filled while DEBUG) being called when creating instance while DEBUG. I'm working in PyCharm.

This is class to find attributes...

```
class ListTree:
    def __attrnames(self,obj,indent):
        spaces=' '*(indent+1)
        result=''
        for attr in sorted(obj.__dict__):
            if attr.startswith('__') and attr.endswith('__'):
                result+=spaces+f'{attr}\n'
            else:
                result+=spaces+f'{attr}={getattr(obj,attr)}\n'
        return result

    def __listclass(self, aClass, indent):
        dots = '.' * indent
        if aClass in self.__visited:
            return '\n{0}<Class {1}:, address {2}: (see above)>\n'.format(
                dots,
                aClass.__name__,
                id(aClass))
        else:
            self.__visited[aClass] = True
            here = self.__attrnames(aClass, indent)
            above = ''
            for super in aClass.__bases__:
                above += self.__listclass(super, indent + 4)
            return '\n{0}<Class {1}, address {2}:\n{3}{4}{5}>\n'.format(
                dots,
                aClass.__name__,
                id(aClass),
                here, above,
                dots)

    def __str__(self):
        print('hello world from __str__')
        self.__visited = {}
        here = self.__attrnames(self, 0)
        above = self.__listclass(self.__class__, 4)
        return '<Instance of {0}, address {1}:\n{2}{3}>'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__,
            id(self),
            here, above)
```

These are classes to be printed

```
class Super():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data1 = 'spam'

    def ham(self):
        pass

class Sub(Super, ListTree):
    def __init__(self):
        Super.__init__(self)
        self.data2 = 'eggs'
        self.data3 = 42

    def spam(self):
        pass

instanse = Sub()
print(instanse)
```

The ouput from RUN is :

```
hello world from __str__
<Instance of Sub, address 140389925768448:
 _ListTree__visited={}
 data1=spam
 data2=eggs
 data3=42

....<Class Sub, address 28451744:
     __doc__
     __init__
     __module__
     spam=<function Sub.spam at 0x7faf13a1b670>

........<Class Super, address 28450800:
         __dict__
         __doc__
         __init__
         __module__
         __weakref__
         ham=<function Super.ham at 0x7faf13a1b550>

............<Class object, address 9435264:
```

The ouput from DEBUG is :

```
...
...(lots of repeating hello world from __str__)
...
hello world from __str__
hello world from __str__
hello world from __str__
hello world from __str__
hello world from __str__
hello world from __str__
hello world from __str__
<Instance of Sub, address 140359544124464:
 _ListTree__visited={<class '__main__.Sub'>: True, <class '__main__.Super'>: True, <class 'object'>: True, <class '__main__.ListTree'>: True}
 data1=spam
 data2=eggs
 data3=42

....<Class Sub:, address 41729904: (see above)>
>
```

Comment: In all likelihood your debugger is using `str(value)` to show you variables in the debug panel.

Comment: However, why should `__visited` be an instance attribute? Why not just pass those in as function arguments instead?

Comment: What is different? Edit the question to show an example output as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm, and more globally IntelliJ IDEA IDEs, repeateadly call the string converter on your local variables to display their values in the the debug panel.

In Python, this string converter is `str` which call the `__str__` method of your object. If your `__str__` method has side-effects (like outputting something on `stdout`) then this side effect will happen many times (at least, each time your press the `Next` button in the debugger, sometimes more).